# No overload method for my procedure

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that holds three arrays: one for the person's last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number. Now, I've got all the arrays and everything done but when I try to call my `ProcessDelete` method I keep getting

> The best overload method match for
>   'playersystem6.program.ProcessDelete(int[], ref int)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Some guidance in the right direction would really help.

```
static Int32[] ProcessDelete(Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount)
        {
            Int32[] newArray = new Int32[playerNumbers.Length - 1]; 

            int index = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (index < playerNumbers.Length)
            {
                if (index != playerCount)
                {
                    newArray[j] = playerNumbers[index];
                    j++;
                }

                index++;
            }

            return newArray;          
        }

        static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to delete
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {
                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, playerCount);

               if (playerindex != -1)
                {
                    {    
                        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex] );
                        Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `playerindex = ProcessDelete(playerNumbers ref playerCount);` - the method is expecting the `ref` keyword in front of the second argument.  The real questino is why are you using `ref`?  You're not doing anything to `playerCount` in the method.

Comment: `playerindex = ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, ref playerCount);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
playerindex = ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, playerCount);
```

Add the `ref` keyword in front of `playercount` to explicitly tell it that it is passed by reference:

```
playerindex = ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, ref playerCount);
```