# How to remove array element from user entered array

Tags: c#

HI I'm creating a menu driven program that holds three arrays: one for the person's last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number. I made a deletemethod and deleteplayer method that is suppose to when the user enters a players number delete the player number, last name and points from the user entered list but when I use the delete method it clears the entire list. I am not sure on on how to fix this. I also have to keep the program in the main class.

Any Help would be appreciated please and thank you

```
    static void ProcessDelete( Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount,  String[] playerLastName,  Int32[] playerPoints)
        {

            Int32[] newArray = new Int32[playerNumbers.Length]; String[] newArray2 = new String[playerLastName.Length]; Int32[] newArray3 = new Int32[playerPoints.Length];

            int index = Array.IndexOf(playerNumbers, 0);


            {
                for (int i = 0; i < playerNumbers.Length; i++)
                    playerNumbers[i] = 0;
            }

            // String[] playerLastName = new String[] { null, null, null };


            for (int i = 0; index < playerLastName.Length; index++)

                    playerLastName[i] = " ";

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(newArray2[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < playerPoints.Length; i++)
                playerPoints[i] = 0;
        }

        static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to delete
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {

                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);


               if (playerindex != -1)
                {

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastName[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        ProcessDelete( playerNumbers, ref playerCount,  playerLastName, playerPoints);
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about why aren't you using a class named Player (for example) that has public properties for the Number, the LastName and the Points of the player and then you manage a list of Player objects to perform operations. Handling three separated lists of information that are logically related is not a good practice.

Comment: You seem to be a very good friend of josh909 :-)    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703637/no-overload-method-for-my-procedure/26703677#26703677](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703637/no-overload-method-for-my-procedure/26703677#26703677)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an object-oriented language, you would generally create a class to capture this information.
Let me know if you need any explanation because, as always, there's more than one way to do this.

**Updated with CurrentScore, AddPlayerToGame() function, and incrementing playercount**

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        //Create firstPlayer
        Player firstPlayer = new Player {
            PlayerId = 1,
            DisplayName = "Goober",
            LastName = "Smith"
        };

        // Create secondPlayer
        Player secondPlayer = new Player {
            PlayerId = 2,
            DisplayName = "Destructor",
            LastName = "Henry"
        };

        // Create game instance
        Game currentGame = new Game();
        // Add players to game
        currentGame.AddPlayerToGame(firstPlayer);
        currentGame.AddPlayerToGame(secondPlayer);

        // Player scores a point
        secondPlayer.CurrentScore++;

        // Player clicks LeaveGame, etc.
        currentGame.PlayerLeavesGame(firstPlayer);
    }
}


public class Player {
    public int PlayerId { get; set; } // I assume the same as player numbers
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CurrentScore { get; set; }
}

public class Game {
    private static readonly int MAXPLAYERS = 10;
    public Game() {
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }
    public List<Player> Players { get; private set; }

    private int _PlayerCount = 0;
    public int PlayerCount {
        get {
            return _PlayerCount;
        }
        set {
            _PlayerCount = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to add a player to the game
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="playerThatJoinedGame"></param>
    /// <returns>True if the player was added and the game wasn't full</returns>
    public bool AddPlayerToGame(Player playerThatJoinedGame) {
        if (PlayerCount < MAXPLAYERS) {
            Players.Add(playerThatJoinedGame);
            PlayerCount++;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }


    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a player from the game
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="playerThatQuit">The leaving player</param>
    public void PlayerLeavesGame(Player playerThatQuit) {
        // Removes the player from the game
        Players.Remove(playerThatQuit);
        PlayerCount--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the information in the lists is logically related why aren't you using Lists or Dictionaries?

Something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Player{
    public int Number;
    public string LastName;
    public int Points;
}

class PlayerManager{
    static Dictionary<int,Player> dctOfPlayers= new Dictionary<int, Player>();

    public static AddNewPlayer(Player newPlayer){
        dctOfPlayers.Add(newPlayer.Number,newPlayer);
    }

    public static RemovePlayer(int playerNumber){
        dctOfPlayers.Remove(playerNumber);
    }
}
```

You could use a list of Players and make loops to find the user ID too...

Also if for any reason you want to preserve the Player entry and just reset the information then you can:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Player{
    public int Number;
    public string LastName;
    public int Points;

    public ResetInfo(){
        Number=0;
        LastName="";
        Points=0;
    }
}

class PlayerManager{
    static Dictionary<int,Player> dctOfPlayers= new Dictionary<int, Player>();

    public static AddNewPlayer(Player newPlayer){
        dctOfPlayers.Add(newPlayer.Number,newPlayer);
    }

    public static RemovePlayer(int playerNumber){
        dctOfPlayers[layerNumber].ResetInfo();
    }
}
```